# post method not allowed in iis Express

Tags: .net, wcf

I am trying to learn to develop a web service using WCF.

I want to use a post method for this example as I have implemented `Get` method already. The code is :

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
           RequestFormat= WebMessageFormat.Json,
           ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
           UriTemplate = "Json/{id}")]
public void JsonData(string id)
{
     return "id is :" + id;
}
```

This is showing method not allowed when I am using a post method at the place of get but its working in get method.

Please help me.

Comment: The code you have shown is unlikely to even compile because your `JsonData` is defined as `void` and inside you are attempting to return a value.

Comment: Thats true I have made a changes before that it was string as a return type. It was wrongly posted as void. Its still string as a return type
still that is showing same error.

Comment: And I am using iis Express Not the local iis server The Get method is working fine but not post

Comment: How are you trying to **test** this `POST` method? You cannot just browse to the URL...... you'll need something like Fiddler or Postman to send a `POST` request to your URL

Comment: Hi have fiddler but How do I post request using that can you please suggest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have Fiddler, you need to go to the `Composer` tab, pick the method of `POST`, enter your URL, and then hit `Execute`:

[image]

Comment: thanks Marc_s I did that and its giving me output as I am returning string from function. But for a knowledge base can you please explain me why it is not running on browser Because ultimately I need to access this function using desktop application